# Using PsExec.exe in java

Tags: java, psexec

I try to connect a remote machine using ***PsExec.exe***, and i want to do some work to this machine. 
Normally i send the request to the remote machine, it works fine but after it finishes,it doesnt return anything but it should be normally. I thought ***PsExec.exe*** hangs thats why it couldnt return anything.

here is the java code that i use :

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

and the command is :

> String command = "cmd /c c:\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\" + availableHost.getHostName()
>                   + " java -cp c:\sahi\lib\ant-sahi.jar net.sf.sahi.test.TestRunner -test " + waitingTestSet.getPath() + " -browserType "
>                   + waitingTestSet.getBrowserType() + " -baseURL " + waitingTestSet.getUrl() + " -host localhost -port 9999 -threads "
>                   + waitingTestSet.getThread() + " -useSingleSession false -tSetId " + waitingTestSet.getTestSetID() + " -u "
>                   + availableHost.getuName() + " -p " + availableHost.getuPass() + " -conStr " + connectionString;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
cmd /c c:\PSTools\PsExec.exe
```

Will cause you to launch a `cmd.exe` process which in turn launches the `PsExec.exe`. You may think "Oh, but thats what I want" but its not.

The flag you use with `cmd` actually does the following:

```
 /C     Run Command and then terminate
```

So immediately after the the `PsExec.exe` process gets launched from the `cmd.exe`, the `cmd.exe` process is finished because its only job was to start the `PsExec.exe` process and terminate. So from the Java standpoint, everything is done.

Just try running the `PsExex.exe` directly and see if that returns the output you desire.

Comment: again, it didnt terminate psexec!!

Comment: Print out your `command` String and run it in a command prompt. What happens?

Comment: I think its actually a bug with PsExec. See: http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-always-hangs-when-run-from-java_topic5013_page1.html

Comment: What version did you end up using? `1.58`?